# CMake find_package found but can't link to library

Tags: cmake

I have in my workspace a library "serial" (serial.lib) and exe project, where the exe needs to link to the library for building and linking.

In my exe CMakeList.txt, itdoesn't seem to have any problem with `find_package(serial)`:

```
Found serial: 1.2.1 (D:/../install/share/serial/cmake)
```

Here is my CMake:

```
...
    include_directories(include ${serial_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    find_package(serial REQUIRED)
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} serial)
    #Do i need the following?
    add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} serial)
...
```

However, it can't seem to find the "serial.lib" which was already built and available in the install\lib\serial directory.

`${serial_INCLUDE_DIRS}` prints out the correct directory: install/include

If I add the line:

```
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} serial)
```

I will end up with error: `The dependency target "serial" of target "test" does not exist.`

What was missing? Is there a need to add the `link_directories(...)`? How do I specify that, if `${serial_INCLUDE_DIRS}` can point to the correct directory, is there such a thing as `${serial_LIBS}` which will point to the library directory? I tried the `${serial_LIBS}` and this seems to be just empty.

Comment: An effect of `find_package(XXX)` depends on `FindXXX.cmake` or `XXXConfig.cmake` script which is actually processed by this command. Many scripts set `XXX_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `XXX_LIBRARIES` variable, so if you found `serial_INCLUDE_DIR` variable to be set, then `serial_LIBRARIES` variable is likely set too. If this doesn't work (that is, empty), you may check `serial_LIBRARY` variable. You may also read the script in the directory `D:/../install/share/serial/cmake` as CMake shows you.

Comment: I manged to build and link after adding this line to the library CMakeList ament_export_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME})

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you found a solution to your issue, please consider writing an answer post to describe how you fixed the problem, and showing the code that you changed. That way, future visitors to your question can learn from it.